# Преобразование класса-наследника к классу-родителю в Java

Tags: java, классы

У меня есть два класса:

- `class a` (**Parent**)
- `class b` (**Child**)

  `b extend a`

> Эти классы только хранят данные как структура, не более того.

Мне нужно преобразовать `class b` в `class a`.

Я знаю что это совсем делать не нужно, так как он и без того является наследником `class a`. Но я использую библиотеку, которая сохраняет объекты именно по их принадлежности.

Я получаю в конструкторе `class a` объект `class b`, и там вручную присваиваю все поля. Но такое решение плохо выглядит, тем более там порядка 30 полей.

Можно ли как-то сделать это через цикл, или вовсе автоматизировать этот процесс?

*P.S. Java я использую в Android разработке.*

**UPD**:

У этих классов нет гетеров и сетеров; все их поля, которые нужно заполнить, публичные, и я их сам до этого момента вручную не присваиваю — это делает библиотека где-то внутри.

Answer (score 4):

Если оба класса имеют геттеры-сеттеры на все копируемые поля, можно использовать Apache Commons BeanUtils, метод [copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object).

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(a, b);
```

Я собрал для вас рабочий пример [прямо на гитхабе](https://github.com/holy-shit/stackoverflowru-q488393).
Если у вас установлен maven, то запустить его можно с помощью mvn clean install, mvn exec:java

Суть можно проиллюстрировать вот этим примером:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Готовим исходные данные
        B b = new B();
        b.setX("123");
        A a = new A();

        //Копируем поля между классами
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(a, b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Вот эта строчка должна вывести только плохое
        test(b);

        //А вот это уже хорошее!
        test(a);

    }

    public static void test(A a) {
        if (a.getClass().equals(A.class)) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Все просто замечательно, и значение = %s", a.getX()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ты пытаешься выполнить меня с неверным классом!");
        }
    }
}
```

Конечно, чтобы это заработало, нужно иметь в classpath сами BeanUtils, что проще всего сделать добавив в Maven новую зависимость:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Если этот метод почему-то не подходит (например, у вас используются не бины), опишите проблему дательней, я попробую сообразить копирование полей совсем вручную, с помощью рефлекшена.

Comment: Этот вариант к сожалению не подходит, так как у полей может (скоре всего) не быть гетеров и сетеров, это просто классы для хранения информации как структура не более того, поэтому наверное придется методами рефлекшена, если вам не трудно то не могли бы пример с ним? Сейчас добавлю информацию о классах.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать все еще проще. Вот пример:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DerivedNode dn = new DerivedNode();
        Derived d = new Derived(dn);
        d.bar( dn );
    }
}

class Base{
    protected BaseNode n;
    public Base(BaseNode _n){
        this.n = _n;
    }

    public void foo(BaseNode x){
        n.foo(x);
    }
}


class BaseNode{
    public void foo(BaseNode x){
        System.out.println( "BaseNode foo" );
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    public Derived(BaseNode n){
        super(n);
    }

    public void bar(DerivedNode x){
        if( n instanceof DerivedNode ){
            // приведение типа
            ((DerivedNode)n).bar(x);
        }
        else {
            // кидаем ошибку
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Object Type");
        }
    }
}

class DerivedNode extends BaseNode{
    public void bar(BaseNode b){
        System.out.println( "DerivedNode bar" );
    }
}
```